# Why does the chart only render when I refresh, but disappear when I navigate away and come back?

Tags: meteor

I'm using iron-router and chartist, and I have a template `chart` that shows the chart when I refresh the page, but not when I navigate away and come back.  The div still exists, and the space is taken up, but the chart isn't showing.

```
Template.chart.onRendered(function () {

    new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
        labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        series: [
            [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
            [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
            [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        ]
    }, {
        fullWidth: true,
        chartPadding: {
            right: 40
        }
    });
});
```

https://atmospherejs.com/mfpierre/chartist-js

Below does work, but it's clearly not the correct way to do this:

```
 Template.chart.onRendered(function () {

setTimeout(function() {

    new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
        labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        series: [
            [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
            [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
            [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        ]
    }, {
        fullWidth: true,
        chartPadding: {
            right: 40
        }
    });

  },2000); 
});
```

In my router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('join');
    this.route('chart');
    //etc.
})
```

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your error, but can't.

Comment: I tried what you wrote and it works without error.  I'm not sure but when I wrapped mine in a setTimeout then it did work.  I suppose that the function is running before the template exists or something along those lines.  I tried `waitOn:` in the Router.map function, but no luck.

Comment: `Meteor.defer(function() {....` did not work in replacement of a setTimeout

Comment: and I'm assuming that `.ct-chart` is inside the `chart` template?

Comment: Yes it is inside the template

Comment: Hmm, beats me. `waiton` has nothing to do with it. You are not using any data from the collections here. Without seeing more code we won't be able to say what might be causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your error. The following works just fine and I can navigate between the two routes without problems (the chart reappears when navigating back from `other`).

HTML:

```html
<head>
  <title>chartist</title>
</head>

<template name="chart">
  <div class="ct-chart">
    Chart
  </div>
  {{#linkTo route="other"}}other{{/linkTo}}
</template>

<template name="other">
  Other
  {{#linkTo route="chart"}}chart{{/linkTo}}
</template>
```

JS:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.chart.onRendered(function () {

        new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
            labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
            series: [
                [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
                [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
                [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
            ]
        }, {
            fullWidth: true,
            chartPadding: {
                right: 40
            }
        });
    });
}


Router.route('/chart', function () {
    this.render('chart');
});

Router.route('/other', function () {
    this.render('other');
});
```